# How many ways are there to bag the marbles?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, algorithms

Suppose we have $n$ marbles each tagged with numbers $1$ through $n$. We have bags which are allowed to contain *things* where a *thing* is defined as either $\text{(a)}$ a marble *or* $\text{(b)}$ another bag.

We want to consider all of the ways which we can "bag" the marbles. "Bagging" means that the "end result", so to speak, is having a set of "outer" bags $\{b_1, b_2, b_3 \cdots b_q\}$ such that each marble is contained in one of the outer bags either directly, or indirectly (e.g., a marble  may be within an *inner* bag which is contained in one of the $b_i$'s, and in general this "nesting" can be up to $n$ bags deep).

We have an endless supply of bags at our disposal. This would suggest that there is an issue. We could put one marble in some bag $b_1$, and put $b_1$ in another bag $b_2$, and continue this process arbitrarily so that we have an infinite number of combinations. We don't allow this. *Each bag used must **directly** contain at least one marble.*

Note that we consider the marble combinations as well. For example, if $n=2$, then one idea is to put one marble in a bag $b_1$ and having another bag $b_2$ which contains the other marble along with $b_1.$ This method counts for *two* baggings, since the two marbles can switch roles. The reason the marbles are "tagged" is to stress this point.

Now, onto the problems:

> What is an algorithm to compute the number of all possible baggings as a function of $n$? Can it be done in polynomial time? Is there a mathematical closed form?

I have tried to formalize this below (if there is a mistake in the "formalization", simply go by what I've written above).

***Formal Definition***:

Let $X$ be an arbitrary nonempty finite set. Suppose it has cardinality $n$. To this set, we assign a finite class of sets $B_{X}$. A member of this class is called a "$B_{X}$ set". This assignment is defined recursively.

If $n=1$, then $X = \{x_0\}$ is a singleton set. In this case, the sole $B_{X}$ set is simply $X$.

If $n > 1$, then the $B_{X}$ sets of $X$ are those sets $B$ which satisfy the following: $B \cap X \neq \varnothing$, and $B \setminus (B \cap X) = \{B({X_1}), B({X_2}) \cdots B({X_p})\}$ where $X_1, X_2 \cdots X_p$ are pairwise disjoint with $\bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq p} X_i = X \setminus (B \cap X)$ and each $B(X_i)$ is a $B_{X_i}$ set (this is the recursive part; note $|X_i| < |X|=n$). Note that $B \setminus (B \cap X) = \varnothing$ is also allowed. In particular, this implies that all nonempty subsets of $X$ are $B_{X}$ sets.

It's fairly clear that the recursion terminates.

A *complete bagging* of $X$ is a nonempty finite set $\{b_1, b_2, b_3 \cdots b_q\}$ of sets  where each $b_i$ is a $B_{Y_i}$ set with all of the $Y_i$'s being nonempty, pairwise disjoint and $\bigcup_{1 \leq i \leq q} Y_i = X$.

> The number of complete baggings of $X$ depends solely on $n$. Let $C(n)$ denote this quantity. We want to compute $C(n)$.

Comment: I would suggest calculating the answer by hand for some small values of $n$, and then consulting the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences.

Comment: This sounds like counting trees with labelled leaves satisfying a condition like "each non-leaf is adjacent to a leaf".

Comment: Making any progress, 1122?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Unfortunately not. For $n \geq 6$ it's not easy to compute by hand. No luck with the Online Encyclopedia either.

Comment: What numbers do you get? It's not the same as http://oeis.org/A000311 is it?

Comment: Still here, 1122?

Comment: Just to clarify, can there be more than one bag directly inside another bag?

Comment: @Jens Yes, there can.

Comment: @GerryMyerson No. Jeremy's answer below seems correct. Also, sorry for the delayed response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem breaks down naturally into two parts:

1. Put the marbles into the $k$ bags that contain them.
2. Nest the $k$ bags into other bags.

Fixing a particular value of $k$, the first task can be accomplished in $S(n,k)$ ways, where $S(n,k)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

For the second task, treat the table on which the "outer" bags sit as a "super-bag". Then the bagging including the "super-bag" is a rooted, labelled tree on $k+1$ nodes, of which there are $(k+1)^{k-1}$ possibilities.

Summing these values for $k \in \{1 \ldots n\}$, we find the number of baggings of $n$ objects is $$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n S(n,k) (k+1)^{k-1}$$

The first couple of terms in the sequence are 1, 4, 26, 243, 2992, 45906. Running up a few extra terms and checking in OEIS, this sequence is indexed as [A052880](http://oeis.org/A052880).

Addendum: To address the issue brought up by @Jens, here is an enumeration for $n=3$

1. Three outer bags - 1 way: (A)(B)(C)
2. Two outer bags: - 9 ways: (AB)(C), (AC)(B), and (A)(BC); (A(B))(C), (B(A))(C), (A(C))(B), (C(A))(B), (A)(B(C)), (A)(C(B))
3. One outer bag, three balls in outer bag - 1 way: (ABC)
4. One outer bag, two balls in outer bag - 3 ways: (AB(C)), (AC(B)), (BC(A))
5. One outer bag, one ball in outer bag - 12 ways: there are three ways to pick the ball in the outer bag (say A). Then there are four ways to arrange B & C: (A(BC)), (A(B)(C)), (A(B(C))), (A(C(B))).

Adding yields 26 possible combinations.

Comment: For $n= 1, 2, 3$ I'm getting the result $1, 4, 23$ where the $23$ divides into $1$ combination for $3$ bags, $9$ combinations for $2$ bags and $13$ combinations for $1$ bag. How does this compare with your distribution for $n=3$?

Comment: @Jens: please see edited answer to show my enumeration. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks. I see where we differ. You are assuming it is OK to have more than one bag directly inside a bag. My understanding of the OP was that the allowed contents of a bag was one or more marbles and 0 or 1 bag.

Comment: Nice answer. Is there a simple asymptotic estimate for $\sum_{k=1}^{n} S(n,k)(k+1)^{k-1}$?